# Cannot Debug on Device - closes after splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been trying to get a new machine set up for iPhone development with a new developer account, and have run into a total wall when building / debugging on device. I've gone through all of the official steps to get my certificates and profiles all set up. And everything "seems" to be in order (not my first rodeo).

However, when building on the device the app (blank test app) will display the splash screen and immediately exit (no Xcode output), without ever touching any of my code. Digging into the Device console I get the following trace:

```
TestProject[1029] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.fadetocode.TestProject [TestProject] (675.00)
TestProject[1029] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
TestProject[1029] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/NoAccSplash.dylib
TestProject[1029] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
TestProject[1029] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/PhotoAlbumsPlus.dylib
com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.fadetocode.TestProject[0xc90f]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3730 (25147):3
com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.fadetocode.TestProject[0xc90f]) Assuming job exited: <rdar://problem/5020256>: 10: No child processes
com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.fadetocode.TestProject[0xc90f]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.fadetocode.TestProject[0xc90f]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483645 seconds
SpringBoard[860] <Warning>: Application 'TestProject' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
com.apple.debugserver-64[1018] <Warning>: 1 [03fa/1303]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff819d4, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
```

Additionally, I can then launch the app manually on the device and it works perfectly. And I have used this device in the past for development (about 6 months ago) without any issues.

My setup is thus:

- Device: iPod touch 4th gen (jailbroken) with version 5.0.1
- Base SDK: 5.1
- Deployment target: 5.0
- Xcode: 4.4.1

Comment: I have a similar problem, started after replacing my provisioning profile for one of my project and removing some unused certificates from my device. Now I can't run any project from xcode, but can run them manually. iPhone 3GS 5.1.1. Did you solve this?

Comment: I did find a solution for myself, I just went ahead and started uninstalling apps mentioned in the trace. Once I got rid of Activator and PhotoAlbumsPlus it started to work. It seems as though these were crashing and breaking out of the debugging session.

Comment: Just tested this, and it worked! I disabled completely the mobile substrate by rebooting while pressing the volume-up button and now I can run from x-code. So I'm just left with finding which app I need to remove or re-install. Thanks!